# How to convert video file using VLC with filename from user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, vlc-media-player

I managed to piece together the following, but it's not working.

```
@echo off
SET /p filename=Enter name of the file you want to convert:  "%%PROGRAMFILES%%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv %%filename
--sout='#transcode{vcodec=x264,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=output.mp4}' 
vlc://quit
```

Error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

I can't tell which `path` it's referring to though. I tried to change each part that contained a filename.

I'm also familiar with VLC GUI but never used the CLI until now, so I'm open to input on the VLC syntax too.

#### Update

@s.brottes got me straightened out with the `%filename%` variable. I'm now using:
`"%PROGRAMFILES%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv %cd%\%filename% --sout='#transcode{vcodec=x264,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=%CD%\output.mp4}' vlc://quit`

But now it's not outputting anything and no output file is appearing. Hmm....

Comment: Could you try to use `%filename%` instead of `%%filename` and `%PROGRAMFILES%` instead of `%%PROGRAMFILES%%`

Comment: @S.Brottes Thank you. I got stuck on the `%%` when I tried using `%%~n`. That got rid of the path error!

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set /p "_filename=Enter name of the file you want to convert: "

"%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv ".\%_filename%" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=x264,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=.\output.mp4}" vlc://quit
```

---

**1.** Make sure the path to vlc.exe points to `"%ProgramFiles%"` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`

**2.** Replace this character `'` to `"`

**3.** Check where you need space

---

```powershell
"[%ProgramFiles%]|or|[%ProgramFiles(x86)%]\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv ".\%_filename%" --sout=[Add Space Here][Replace ' to "]#transcode{vcodec=x264,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=.\output.mp4}[Replace ' to "] vlc://quit
```

---